# How to make a div content not overextend

Tags: html, css

I have a div of width for example 100px and when I put content in it, this content overextends beyond the 100px instead of dropping one line. ( I was checking with the inspect tool inside the browser. )
**Note:** this div is placed inside a `<li>` with `display: flex;`

I've tried making the `<div>` to `float: left;` and to `display: inline;` and to `display: inline-block;` but it didn't work...

## CSS

```
.fixed-header #nav-list {
    flex-basis: 80%;
    align-self: flex-start;
}

.fixed-header #nav-list ul {
    list-style: none;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-basis: 100%;   
}

.fixed-header #nav-list ul li {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.fixed-header #nav-list ul .drop-down-element {
    width: 15%;
}

.fixed-header #nav-list ul li div {
    float: left;
}
```

**Note: The** `#nav-list` **is a flex element of** `.fixed-header` (see in the HTML Section).

## HTML

```
<div class="fixed-header">
    <div id="header"><h1>Physi_Cs</h1></div>

    <div id="nav-list">
        <ul>
            <li class="drop-down-element"><a href="#">Shop</a> <div>BLABLA</div> </li>
            <li class="drop-down-element"><a href="#">Learn Physics</a></li>
            <li class="drop-down-element"><a href="#">Articles</a></li>
            <li><a href="SignUpPage.html">Sign Up</a></li>
            <li><a href="LoginPage.html">Log In</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**My question is:** 
How do I make the content of the `<div>` inside of the `<li>` not overextend beyond the `<div>` width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically your only problem was

```css
.fixed-header #nav-list ul .drop-down-element {
   width: 15% 
}
```

It makes the elements' width relative to the available space ignoring any kind of overflow.
So to fix it just remove this rule.